# Pycharm is not letting me run my script 'test_splitter.py' , but instead 'Nosetests in test_splitter.py'?

Tags: python, pycharm

I see many posts on 'how to run nosetests', but none on how to make pycharm et you run a script without nosetests. And yet, I seem to only be able to run or debug 'Nosetests test_splitter.py' and not ust 'test_splitter.py'!

I'm relatively new to pycharm, and despite going through the documentation, I don't quite understand what nosetests are about and whether they would be preferrable for me testing myscript. But I get an error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nose'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1
>
> Empty suite

I don't have administartive access so cannot download nosetests, if anyone would be sugesting it. I would just like to run my script! Other scripts are letting me run them just fine without nosetests!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: I can run without nosetests from the 'Run' dropdown options in the toolbar, or Alt+Shift+F10.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you are using an interpreter which doesn't have the nosetests installed.

You can configure your project interpreter from: **File > Settings > Project Interpreter**

[image]

[image]

[image]